# replacement of SetThreadIdealProcessor in pthread, Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, winapi, pthreads, porting

I'm porting a multi-thread application from Win32 to Linux.

In Win32 we use `SetThreadIdealProcessor` to set a 'preferred' processor for a thread, and I'm looking for help on providing a similar solution in Linux with pthread.

Note here: `pthread_setaffinity_np` in pthread.h is not a 'good' solution here, since it would limit the thread to run ONLY on the specified CPU set. Actually `pthread_setaffinity_np` is nearly equivalent to `SetThreadAffinityMask function` in Win32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such functionality exists in Linux. A processor is either in the mask of allowed processor or not.

Comment: Yep dude, I've also found it not possible (at least for now) to do such things in Linux with NPTL. I'm now trying to simply use CPU masks (pthread_setaffinity_np) instead. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: One question that pops to my mind, probably because I'm a Linux rather then a windows geek - what good is such an API? I'm trying to understand what it is useful for and failing.

Comment: Our algorithms would arrange those threads to their specified CPU cores, and in most cases it would work fine. But since some cores might be acquired for a relatively long time(etc. by another process with higher priority), our strategy may fail to give a good performance. So I want a thread to "prefer" some core instead of to "lock on". btw, I'm also a Linux guy than a windows one :D

Comment: @PengyuCHEN: You should probably just allow the scheduler to distribute the threads among the cores itself - it usually does a pretty good job (in other words, replace `SetThreadIdealProcessor` with a no-op on Linux).